# Is it possible to have multiple CASE statements in a single sqlplus select statement?

Tags: html, sql, oracle, case, markup

I previously asked a question about formatting sqlplus output in HTML using a CASE statement.

I have been asked to amend the report to include a new column, which I have easily, but I would like to 'CASE' this column output so that it is colour coded within html

```
select upper(lpad(country,6,' ')) cntry, max(timestamp) Timestamp,substr(LPAD(test_type,10,' '),0,10) Type,
CASE
        WHEN ((sysdate-max(timestamp))*1440) >=60 THEN '<span class="threshold-critical">'|| ' <======= ERROR over 60 minutes since last run'||'</span>'
        WHEN ((sysdate-max(timestamp))*1440) >=30 THEN '<span class="threshold-warning">'|| '<===== WARNING over 30 minutes since last run'||'</span>'
    ELSE '<span class="threshold-ok">'|| '<===== GOOD_____' ||'</span>'
    end status,
CASE
   WHEN (ROUND(AVG((NVL(s2_time,0)+NVL(s3_time,0)+NVL(s4_time,0)+NVL(s5_time,0)+NVL(s6_time,0)+NVL(s7_time,0)+NVL(s8_time,0)+NVL(s9_time,0)+NVL(s10_time,0))/1000),1)) >=60 THEN '<span class="average-critical"</span>'
   WHEN (ROUND(AVG((NVL(s2_time,0)+NVL(s3_time,0)+NVL(s4_time,0)+NVL(s5_time,0)+NVL(s6_time,0)+NVL(s7_time,0)+NVL(s8_time,0)+NVL(s9_time,0)+NVL(s10_time,0))/1000),1)) >=35 THEN '<span class="average-warning"</span>'
   ELSE '<span class="average-ok"</span>'
END Average
from rfgdba.perf_test_results ptr, rfgdba.perf_tests pt
where country is not null and test_id in ((select id from rfgdba.perf_tests where live='Y')) and test_type in ('ORACLE','SIEBEL') 
and timestamp > sysdate-(59/1440) and ptr.test_id=pt.ID
group by country, test_type
order by country, TRUNC(timestamp, 'HH24')
```

any ideas why this doesnt work?

output example - which strangely shows it works from sqlplus

[image: sqlplus output for CASE in select statement]

Comment: "Doesn't work"? What error are you getting?

Comment: shouldn't `rem new CASE statement added below` be commented?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly use more than one `CASE` expression in a `SELECT`. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? It would be helpful if you'd [create an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4), populated with tables and data, so that people can help you figure out what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: @nyehus: Please post the exact exception message in your question

Comment: the 'rem new CASE' line I just entered to show the new line, with regards to the error - I dont get anything - well not that I can find

Comment: But that looks part of your code. Give the **exact** SQL query, what error are you getting, some sample data in tables and your expected output based on that. SQLFiddle example would have been better.

Comment: So the query returns no records?

Comment: comment line removed from my code

Comment: I have just extracted the sql code from my script and ran it in toad - and it returns output - see image uploaded - so it would seem the issue is with my copy of the set_markup file that is creating the output in html format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work, simple example:

```
-- some test data
with data as
 (select 1 as id, 'A' as val
    from dual
  union
  select 2, 'B' from dual)
select case
         when id = 1 then
          '1'
         else
          'not 1'
       end as col1,
       case
         when val = 'B' then
          'B'
         else
          'not B'
       end as col2
  from data
```

see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/7785

Comment: many thanks - turned out to be syntax errors, as the sql code ran successfully in toad, but not in my windows script, plus also had an error in my set_markup config file - all working as expected now